# How to make use of an array returned by a function? in C language

Tags: arrays, c, return-value, variable-length-array

My general goal with this question is to understand how to make use (say, print) of an array returned from an outer function. I'm using prime numbers as an example.
I'm new so going in-depth explaining... Sorry if there's un-needed info or misused terms :)

I defined a function "findprimes" to find every prime between 1 and x.
The function successfully *prints* an array of primes. However, I don't know if it *returns* the array of primes. And, if it does, I have no idea how to use said array in main().

This is the function 'findprimes':

```
int* findprimes(int x) {

    int i, j, total=0;
    int* numbers = (int*)malloc((x + 1) * sizeof(int));

    /* initialization */
    for (i = 0; i <= x + 1; i++) {
        numbers[i] = 1;
    }

    /* find primes and assign prime=1 */
    for (i = 2; i < sqrt(x); i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == 1) {
            for (j = i * i; j <= x; j = j + 2) {
                if (j % i == 0) {
                    numbers[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* count how many primes */
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == 1) {
            total++;
        }
    }

    /* put primes into their own array */
    int* primes = (int*)malloc(total * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 1,j=0; i <= x; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == 1) {
            primes[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    //I want this part to be in main()
    printf("The prime numbers between 1 and %d are: ", x);
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%d ", primes[i]);
    }
    
    return primes;
}
```

I want to print the 'primes' array in main, not in the function 'findprimes' itself. How can I do this?

```
int main() {

    int n;

    do {
        printf("Enter a value for X>2: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n <= 2);

    findprimes(n); //This returns 'primes' array

    //I want to print 'primes' array here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the return value in `main()`:

```
int *primes = findprimes(n);
```

and use the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_magic_number; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", primes[i]);
}
```

and remember to free the memory:

```
free(primes);
```

In fact, you also need to free `numbers` in the function.

The `some_magic_number` needs to be known — how does the `main()` function know how many elements are in the array?  One way to fix that is to pass a pointer to the function that can hold the number of primes:

```
int *findprimes(int n, int *num_primes)
```

and use `*num_primes = total;` in the function before returning.
You could call the function with:

```
int some_magic_number;
int *primes = findprimes(n, &some_magic_number);
```

You'd probably choose an alternative name for the variable in `main()`, but it illustrates my point.

Comment: unrelated: `numbers` in `findprimes` also needs to be `free`ed before the function returns.

Comment: @user4581301 — yes.  There's also the problem that the array is returned but there's no length, and that complicates the printing (a lot).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm trying to do this but can't get the syntax right... How do I write the return() part of 'findprimes'? I added the `int *num_primes` part in the function and wrote:
`*num_primes = total;
return(primes, &*num_primes);`
So it should return both of them, no?

Comment: You can only return one value from a function.  That's why I suggested the extra pointer parameter.  Alternatively, you could create a structure type with a length and a pointer and return that.

Comment: Problem was I didn't use correct syntax. I now understand your solution and it's great, thank you! However a new problem emerged... [link](https://ibb.co/VDCz93M)

Comment: Not sure what's happening there.  When I take your code and my changes, I can run with 100 as the limit without visible problems.  The algorithm reports 1 as a prime — it isn't regarded as a prime any more. A Google search for "Is one a prime number" yields "No" and the explanation: _In the 19th century many mathematicians still considered 1 to be prime, and lists of primes that included 1 continued to be published as recently as 1956. If the definition of a prime number were changed to call 1 a prime, many statements involving prime numbers would need to be reworded in a more awkward way._